# Python open file exception, how do I know detailed exception information?

Tags: python

Question as in code comment.

```
try:
    with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f1:
        f1.read(...)

    with open('file2.txt', 'rb') as f2:
        f2.read(...)
        f2.write(...)

except IOError as e:
    # How do I know which file throwed the exception? So to report a friendly error message.
    # Further, can I know if the exception is caused by open, read, or write?
```

Comment: Consider using `traceback`

Comment: @zondo, that is incorrect. In Python 2.7 and 3.4, IO exceptions are not caught by the `open()` context manager.

Answer (score 0):

As Ian said, you could try to parse the traceback to figure out what error occured and where.  However, it would be easier to use two try catch blocks:

```
try:
    with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f1:
        f1.read(...)

except IOError as e:
    # do something about error opening or reading f1

try:
    with open('file2.txt', 'rb') as f2:
        f2.read(...)
        f2.write(...)

except IOError as e:
    # do something about error opening/reading/writing f2
```